C++ TypeList with template types has index and type operations that don't work together
For a project I'm working on I have been trying to implement a typelist with template class's as the possible types, the relevant parts of my implementation are below. It works well generally but it does not work as expected when I combine some of the utility types / operations together.
// template class typelist
template <template <class> class ... TemplateTypes>
struct TemplateTypeList {};

// utility types for TemplateTypeList
// type at index of typelist
template <std::size_t I, class TypeList>
struct TemplateTypeListType;

template <template <class> class First, template <class> class ... RestOfTypeList>
struct TemplateTypeListType<0, TemplateTypeList<First, RestOfTypeList...>> {
    template <class T>
    using result = First<T>;
};

template <std::size_t I, template <class> class First, template <class> class ... RestOfTypeList>
struct TemplateTypeListType<I, TemplateTypeList<First, RestOfTypeList...>> {
    template <class T>
    using result = typename TemplateTypeListType<I - 1, TemplateTypeList<RestOfTypeList...>>::template result<T>;
};

// index of type in typelist
template <template <class> class TypeToFind, class TypeList>
struct TemplateTypeListIndex;

template <template <class> class TypeToFind, template <class> class ... RestOfTypes>
struct TemplateTypeListIndex<TypeToFind, TemplateTypeList<TypeToFind, RestOfTypes ...>> {
    static const int result = 0;
};

template <template <class> class TypeToFind, template <class> class First, template <class> class ... RestOfTypes>
struct TemplateTypeListIndex<TypeToFind, TemplateTypeList<First, RestOfTypes...>> {
    private:
        using ResultOfPrior = TemplateTypeListIndex<TypeToFind, TemplateTypeList<RestOfTypes...>>;
    public:
        static const int result =  ResultOfPrior::result == -1 ? -1 : ResultOfPrior::result + 1;
};

template <template <class> class TypeToFind>
struct TemplateTypeListIndex<TypeToFind, TemplateTypeList<>> {
    static const int result = -1;
};

The implementation works fine for most of my cases but when I use TemplateTypeListIndex with the result of a TemplateTypeListType It does not seem to work, here is an example:
template <class T>
struct Class1 {};

template <class T>
struct Class2 {};

using Types = TemplateTypeList<Class1, Class2>;

int index = TemplateTypeListIndex<TemplateTypeListType<0, Types>::result, Types>::result;

ASSERT_EQ(index, 0); // fails, index == -1

I am pretty stumped because it works in almost every other case I have used it for. Is there some assumption I am making with my template specializations that is incorrect causing this problem?

See matching-alias-template-as-template-argument.

@Jarod42 Is it a bug in gcc that accepts it? example

I would say "Sort of". There was papers/CWGs to resolve/clarify the issue. gcc might have implement one of them before it has been accepted (or rejected). there might also be some part unclear/subject to interpretation (at least at some time).

So as pointed out in a comment, this does seem to be a consequence of the temp.alias part of the c++ specification, which basically states that template alias's cannot be equal, only template specializations can be. To get around this I created a dummy specialization in TemplateTypeListIndex and now using TemplateTypeListType with TemplateTypeListIndex works:
// index of type in typelist
template <template <class> class TypeToFind, class TypeList>
struct TemplateTypeListIndex;

template <template <class> class TypeToFind, template <class> class First, template <class> class ... RestOfTypes>
struct TemplateTypeListIndex<TypeToFind, TemplateTypeList<First, RestOfTypes...>> {
    private:
        using ResultOfPrior = TemplateTypeListIndex<TypeToFind, TemplateTypeList<RestOfTypes...>>;
        template <class T>
        using IsMatch = std::is_same<TypeToFind<T>, First<T>>;
        struct Dummy {};
    public:
        static const int result =  IsMatch<Dummy>::value ? 0 : ResultOfPrior::result == -1 ? -1 : ResultOfPrior::result + 1;
};

template <template <class> class TypeToFind>
struct TemplateTypeListIndex<TypeToFind, TemplateTypeList<>> {
    static const int result = -1;
};

I realize now that using TemplateTypeListType::result needs to be done with caution because of temp.alias, and I should only use the specialization of the result to compare types in template specializations.
